# How to change between GPU mode and CPU mode in caffe?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I compiled Caffe without copying and editing Makefile.config.example. I tried to run a code in caffe and it shows me CPU mode. My question is that whether it is possible to do refinement on the configuration file after caffe installation? if yes, How?

```
~/caffe-master$ SOME_COMMANDS BLAH BLAH

CPU mode
```

How can I switch the running from ***CPU mode*** to ***GPU mode*** and vice versa?

I really appreciate if you help me. I am beginner in both  caffe and python. Thanks

Comment: Have you built it with GPU support? If you did not make any edits than by default you got CPU-only build.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski i did not do any changes on configuration file. How can I do these changes from CPU into GPU? Should I remove caffe and compile it from beginning again?

Comment: How did you compile your `caffe`, on windows or ubuntu?

Comment: I compiled on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your Caffe?  The [official BVLC release](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) comes as a GPU build by default.

First, Makefile.config has a pair of lines:

```
# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1
```

You have to uncomment this to get a CPU-only build.

Then the final line of each solver file is

```
solver_mode: GPU
```

You need to change this to **CPU** to get CPU execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked  `Makefile.config`, it is already commented. and `solver_mode is on GPU`

Comment: Okay ... that's weird for me.  If I forget to change those, the software yells at me for trying to run in GPU mode.